# Same timestamp across multiple statements

Tags: java, logging, junit, timestamp, timing

I am seeing an issue where multiple statements are being executed, but the timestamp remains the same.

Below the log is showing part of a Spring batch job where reads are happening, data is processed and then written, and then this happens again for the next data set.

The issue in particular is the `timestamp=20200330085053599253` value, which I am expecting to be unique. Increasing the logging level will produce different values for the timestamp; I assume due to the delay caused by the additional logging.

Also important to note is these are tests being run on an imdb.

```
2020-03-30 08:50:53.583 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.Reader : Retrieving clients
2020-03-30 08:50:53.583 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.Reader : Retrieving target
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : client 1001
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : Create CREDIT
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : Create DEBIT
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : Calling service
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.service.Service : timestamp=20200330085053599253
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.service.Service : timestamp=20200330085053599253
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.writer.Writer : Writing list
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.Reader : Retrieving clients
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.Reader : Retrieving target
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : client 1002
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : Create DEBIT
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : client 1003
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : Create DEBIT
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : Create CREDIT
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.s.impl.ServiceImpl : Calling service
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.service.Service : timestamp=20200330085053599253
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.service.Service : timestamp=20200330085053599253)
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.service.Service : timestamp=20200330085053599253
2020-03-30 08:50:53.599 DEBUG   --- [         task-1] c.e.b.c.writer.Writer : Writing list
```

Comment: If I interpret the value `20200330085053599253` correctly, it has microsecond precision (6 decimals on the second: 2020-03-30 08:50:53.599253). (1) Is it unthinkable that more than one timestamp value could be produced in a microsecond? (2) Are you sure your clock (your time source) also has microsecond granularity? There’s a difference between producing a timestamp with microsecond *precision* (anybody can do that) and one with microsecond *accuracy* (which requires a clock with a high definition).

Comment: Yeah,sorry I should've made the timestamp format clear but thats correct. The timestamp is produced from LocalDateTime.now() with format yyyyMMddhhmmssSSSSSS. I am sure my clock does not have that granularity, and the next timestamp produced would be many milliseconds later, but I assume the clock is hardware dependent and also with typical hardware this would be a common problem for anyone unfortunate enough to make the decision of requiring a unique timestamp. I was thinking of simply incrementing the timestamp by a microsecond if a duplicate was found.

Comment: Incrementing by 1 microsecond until you get an unused timestamp sounds like the viable way. Would you post that as an answer, or should I? I’ll be happy to upvote your answer if you post one. Also please paste the information from your comment into your question so we’ve got everything in one place, it’s nicer.